# javascript variable scoping

Tags: javascript, scoping

Why does javascript allow the creation of global variables in local code?
An example

```
function f() { x=10; }
function g() { print(x); }
f(x);
g(x);
```

Comment: A design error. This flaw has been removed in ES5 strict mode.

Comment: Why not? I suppose it could make naming conflicts, but you should be giving better variable names if that is an issue.

Comment: Source for my statement above: http://es5.github.com/#C (fourth bullet)

Comment: And a live demo that demonstrates this: http://jsfiddle.net/simevidas/r3Hjp/1/ (doesn't work in older browsers)

Comment: Thank you Šime, could you post these comments as an answer?

Comment: @titus The currently given answers are valid. My information about strict mode is better left as a comment since nobody is really using strict mode as of now.

Comment: @Sime Vidas - your reference does not say it's a design flaw (it's a common opinion, some reasons here would be nice). There are many flaws in javascript, but it is what it is. Brendan Eich said "[Is JavaScript popular? It’s hard to say. Some Ajax developers profess (and demonstrate) love for it. Yet many curse it, including me.](http://brendaneich.com/tag/javascript/)"

Comment: @RobG Yes, we all pretty much agree that this behavior (creating global variables as a result of assigning to identifiers which cannot be resolved) is a flaw. It's an opinion, yes. Excuse me, did you ask for the reasoning behind this opinion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Why does javascript allow the creation of global variables in local code?

Because it isn't a perfect language.

Use the `var` keyword to limit the scope of variables.

Answer (score 3):

When you don't preface variables with `var` they are automatically in the global scope.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to specify `var` before the variable declaration to make it in scope.